# TouchableOpacity outside parent View in absolute positive not works react native

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, touchablewithoutfeedback

I was making `Picker component` but what I found is `Touchable Opacity` in absolute positions outside from it's parent view not works.

```js
const App = () => {
  const data = [2, 3, 4, 23]
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={setIsOpen.bind(null, true)} disabled={isOpen}>
        <Text>3</Text>
        <Image source={require('./assets/downArrow2.png')} />
        {
          isOpen && (
            <View style={styles.optionsContainer}>
              {
                data.map((number, index) => (
                  <View key={index}> 
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setIsOpen(false) }}>
                      <View style={{ padding: 10, paddingRight: 40 }}>
  
                        <Text>{number}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={{ height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
                  </View>
                ))
              }
            </View>
          )
        }
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 48,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingLeft: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'grey',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  optionsContainer: 
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -1,
    left: -1,
    backgroundColor: 'grey'
  }
})
```

So, There is outer `TouchableOpacity` Component & inside we are mapping many `TouchableOpacity` Component where children are in Absolute View.

`TouchableOpacity` inside it's `parent's view works`, but `not Works outside Parent View with absolute position`. Is their someOne to help me out with it???

> It even Not works with TouchableNativeFeedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TouchableOpacity from **react-native-gesture-handler** solves the issue of absolute position touches. However, it leads to some styling issues such as the overflow "visible" property not working.

So what you can do is that, for the parent TouchableOpacity you can use react-native's TouchableOpacity and for children you can use react-native-gesture-handler's TouchableOpacity to get the touch to work even when positioned absolutely.

This is the updates code. **Please note the imports**.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity as TouchableRN} from 'react-native';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

    const App = () => {
        const data = [2, 3, 4, 23]
        const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <TouchableRN style={styles.container} onPress={setIsOpen.bind(null, true)} disabled={isOpen}>
              <Text>3</Text>
              <Image source={require('./assets/downArrow2.png')} />
              {
                isOpen && (
                  <View style={styles.optionsContainer}>
                    {
                      data.map((number, index) => (
                        <View key={index}> 
                          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setIsOpen(false) }}>
                            <View style={{ padding: 10, paddingRight: 40 }}>
        
                              <Text>{number}</Text>
                            </View>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          <View style={{ height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
                        </View>
                      ))
                    }
                  </View>
                )
              }
            </TouchableRN>
          </View>
        )
      }
      
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
          width: 48,
          paddingVertical: 8,
          paddingRight: 5,
          paddingLeft: 8,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'grey',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
          position: 'relative'
        },
        optionsContainer: {
          position: 'absolute',
          top: -1,
          left: -1,
          backgroundColor: 'grey'
        }
      })
    
      export default App;
```

Comment: Can you tell where to use zIndex in Code in order to show options on Top of every View??